# sudo -u someuserした場合にsudoコマンドを打ったユーザーの秘密鍵の鍵を使いたい

Tags: linux, ssh, sudo

例えば以下のように、SSHでログインした後にsudoでroot権限でコマンドを使う場合を考えます。

ホストOS ==(1)SSH==> ゲストOS vagrantユーザー ==(2)sudo==> ゲストOS rootユーザー

(1)のSSHした後もホストOSの秘密鍵を引き継ぐためには、`~/.ssh/config`のゲストOS vagrantユーザーでのログインのセクションに`ForwardAgent yes`を追加すればよいです。

また(2)のsudo後に秘密鍵を引き継ぐためには、`/etc/sudoers`に`Defaults    env_keep += "SSH_AUTH_SOCK"`を追加すればよいです。

どちらも`ssh-add -l`コマンドで、現在利用できる秘密鍵を確認できます。

現在以下の様な場合で煮詰まっています。

ホストOS ==(1)SSH==> ゲストOS vagrantユーザー ==(3)sudo -u someuser==> ゲストOS someuserユーザー

この(3)の場合、`sudo -u someuser ssh-add -l`を行ってももとのvagrantユーザーで使っている秘密鍵（=ホストOSの秘密鍵）は表示されず、出力は`Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.`となります。

`sudo`にてroot以外のユーザーの権限でコマンドを実行する場合、秘密鍵を引き継ぐ方法はあるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下は回答ではありません。<strike>(頃合いを見て削除します)</strike>

ssh-agent が使用する socket ファイルのパーミッションは、まぁ、当然ではありますが、ssh-agent プロセスの実効ユーザのみが読み書き可能となっています(socket ファイルのあるディレクトリも)。

```
$ ls -l $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
srw------- 1 nemo nemo /tmp/ssh-SnAKKdIr95Ie/agent.1315=
$ ls -ld $(dirname $SSH_AUTH_SOCK)
drwx------ 2 nemo nemo /tmp/ssh-SnAKKdIr95Ie/
```

ではこのパーミッションを変更したら… 非常に危険な状況になりますよね。

以上です。

Comment: なるほど、基本的にやめたほうがよいが強引にできなくもない、ということですね。
socketファイルを観に行くことはしていませんでした。ありがとうございます。是非削除などしないで残しておいていただきたいです。

Comment: @ikuwow ベストアンサーに選んでいただき、どうもありがとうございます。それではこのままにしておきます(少し編集します)。。。

Comment: chmod ではなく、setfacl で someuser にのみ許可を与えると良いと思います。